# How to size a differential amplifier for minimal offset?

Tags: differential-amplifier, offset

What is the strategy for optimizing the offset of the differential amplifier in addition to increasing the size of the cross-coupled transistors? Are there any sizing rules to follow to size the active load for a reduced offset?

Comment: there's actually quite a few approaches. Just to name one that is actually used in opamps: auto-zeroing amplifiers can be implemented by having a pair of amplifiers, one of which switches between feeding back its output to its inverting input while both of its inputs are shorted, so that it "nullifies" its input offset itself; that compensation voltage is stored in a capacitor. Then, in the other phase, the inputs are connected to the signal inputs, which are also fed into the second amplifier, and its output is used, now that we know the first amplifier is zero-offset, to correct the offset

Comment: of the second. Look for "Chopper auto-zero amplifier", there's bound to be a lot of literature on that. It also solves the drift issues that you get with uncompensated differential amplifiers, and *can* be used for noise shaping, as well. Because you now have lower error currents, your "useful" currents can be larger without leading into thermal problems (and heating up isn't as bad – drift compensation!).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are mentioning transistor sizes, I guess you are talking about analog chip design.

Apart from changing the topology to do offset cancellation (chopping or auto-zeroing), optimizing for offset on a differential amplifier is often simply a problem of matching any transistors that appear in both branches of the differential amplifier. This means not just a cross coupled pair in the load, but also the differential input transistors for example (which are probably even more important as they are doing the heavy lifting).

And then you get into a whole other territory of chip design. A few matching tips to keep in mind:

- Make sure your transistor are close together.
- Make sure similar transistors have the same surroundings.
- Make sure your transistors are oriented identically (no mirroring, rotating or flipping!).
- You can use centroiding layouts to improve matching and get rid of first-order gradients (like oxide thickness).
- Make your transistors larger: small imperfections have a smaller relative effect if the transistor is large (or they average out if there are many). This will often interfere with other constraints like (area constraints, gate capacitance, etc.) though so it cannot do the impossible.

Then there is also the choice of the foundry and technology node. There are probably foundries that have a better control over their process than others. Finally, you can also simply measure the offset and grade the device, making this a problem of yield (you just throw away those that have a too-large offset).